# If statement triggers even though it shouldn't

Tags: php, header, get

Here's how it works. If a user clicks on the link to list the products then they will be directed to the products page. For security, I set something at the beginning to assure that either 'cid' or 'sid' is set. I am sure that the users are going to a page linked with cid or sid because it says it as I hover over it in my browser. Here's the code

```
<?php require("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['cid'])||!isset($_GET['sid'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

unfortunately, the users are still directed. I will post more of the code if necessary.

Comment: Replace the `header(...)` call with `var_dump($_GET)`.  What do you see?

Comment: did you session_start()?

Comment: Oli Charlesworth: I got array(1) { ["cid"]=> string(1) "2" }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code requires that *both* `$_GET['cid']` and `$_GET['sid']` are defined, not that one of them is. Replace `||` with `&&` in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if (!(isset($_GET["sid"]) || isset($_GET["cid"])))
```

In your case, assuming an url with `?sid=foo`:

- `!isset($_GET["sid"])` evaluates to false
- `!isset($_GET["cid"])` evaluates to true
- `true || false` evaluates to true, thus the user gets redirected

Answer (score 0):

Change the operator to &&. Like this

```
If(!isset($_GET... && !isset($_GET...)
```